# "Google-served ads obscuring content" issue with Admob banners, do I need to set some paddings but what value?

Tags: android, admob

So I received an email from Google Admob about issue with ads in one of my apps - "Restricted ad serving"   - "Google-served ads obscuring content"

The app has only two banners:

1. at the top of main screen:

[image]

below the banner you can see clickable buttons, can it be the issue? should I increase the padding? but which value? `8dp`, `16dp`, `24dp`, `32dp`? I don't see any official information about paddings for Android

2. at the bottom of settings screen with scrollable list of options:

[image]

Should I add padding between `RecyclerView` and `AdView`? But again which value?

Also what about bottom system navigation panel? There is also no padding. Should I add it as well?

Google AdMob [describes](https://support.google.com/publisherpolicies/answer/11191353#zippy=%2Ctips-for-understanding-this-restriction) possible issues with the following examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I think I don't have such issues like on the examples

Answer (score 2):

the problem is due to your "translucent status bar" resulting in the ads overlapping your background image.

I have a similar problem (mine is a translucent navigation bar rather than a status bar). Admob replied with the following text:

> Upon investigation, it has been identified that the Google banner ad is overlapping with the image, leading to a flag for "Ads Obscuring Content. I have attached a screenshot highlighting this violation for your reference and perusal.

[image]

Comment: not sure about "translucent status bar" and camera preview. That time I just added vertical margins around ad banners, and that's all. For now it's fine. I believe a banner above camera preview should be allowed, it's not clickable element anyway and doesn't have any content like text

Comment: Hi, could you share how on earth did you get a answer from a human?

Comment: @TimAutin, https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9948073 there is a "Contact Us" link, just click and fill in the issue. they will have some one address it. it may take several days, but at least a human will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

1. the problem here is that there is a margin that partially shows the "content" behind the ad.

[image]

Also you should definitely increase the margins of buttons to ensure no accidental clicking occurs. from experience only I find that the best value for top padding is 1/4 of the button height.

2. Also you should definitely make a margin above the list here to ensure no accidental clicking occurs and to let the user (and testing robots) know that these are two different things. from experience only I find that the best value for top padding is 1/4 of the banner height.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean about horizontal margin (on the right from your screenshot), it looks like outlined border which is added by Admob. Anyway it's adaptive ad banner which takes full width but it can take less size then screen's width, it's not for me to decide. But yeah I added vertical margins and it's fixed the issue that time, for now it's all good. I didn't do anything with horizontal margin because there are no margins - AdMob automatically decides how to fill the banner in the container

Comment: `<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/ad_frame_layout" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`